# Jackson XML globally set element name for container types

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, jackson

I'm using Jackson 1.9.2 with the [XML dataformat module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml). I need to tweak the way that Jackson serializes arrays, lists, collections.

By default, with an int array property called `myProperty` containing a couple numbers, Jackson / XML is producing the following:

```
<myProperty>
  <myProperty>1</myProperty>
  <myProperty>2</myProperty>
</myProperty>
```

What I need to produce is:

```
<myProperty>
  <item>1</item>
  <item>2</item>
</myProperty>
```

I can do this on a per-POJO basis using a combination of `JacksonXmlElementWrapper` and `JacksonXmlProperty` like so:

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localname='myProperty')
@JacksonXmlProperty(localname='item')
public int[] myProperty;
```

This solution, however, would require that I manually apply these annotations to every array, list, collection in my POJOs. A much better solution would allow me to apply a solution once, globally, for all array, list, collection types. Any ideas on how to implement such a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could sub-class `AnnotationIntrospector` that XML module provides, and override method that inspects `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper`, and make it return whatever wrapper name you want.

Comment: I like this approach. Any clues how I might do the same for `@JacksonXmlProperty(localName='item')`?

Comment: Yes, that annotation is also handled via `AnnotationIntrospector` so you can rewrite it.

Comment: Sorry to be dense - I see that it can be done with `findSerializablePropertyName`, but I can't simply return `"item"` from that method: I need to selectively return `"item"` when the context is within a non-map container type (list, array or collection). Conditioning `findSerializablePropertyName` in this way is what I don't see how to do.

Comment: Object you get passed can be cast to actual `AnnotatedField` or `AnnotatedMethod`, which gives you bit more access to see if it might be a match. But it is possible that there isn't quite enough information, depending on your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found an easy way to get the information I need to make this workable - thanks again for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating my own `JsonGenerator` to generate XML for the legacy format my group needs to support.

I would have liked to use the Jackson XML dataformat module, which provides more safety, is more tested, and may be faster. Unforunately, I was not able to find a solution using StaxMan's suggestion.

Comment: That is unfortunate, but understandable. One more suggestion: if you are by-passing databinding, you must as well use raw Stax (XML) api (see `javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter`). It's relatively simple to use for content generation, efficient (just remember to reuse `XMLOutputFactory` if you need multiple writers).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Why is it necessary to use? In my `JsonGeneratorBase` subclass I am simply writing `String`s to a stream.

Comment: I would strongly discourage anyone from ever writing XML using String writing -- this will not handle escaping of "funny characters". XMLStreamWriter is typically faster than String concatenation as well.