# Jackson List Help - Java

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I am trying to create some xml with Jackson and I cannot get the list to display like I need.  I am getting:

```
<Messages>
  <Messages>...</Messages>
  <Messages>...</Messages>
</Messages>
```

I want it to look like:

```
<Messages>
  <Message>...</Message>
  <Message>...</Message>
</Messages>
```

My code looks like this:

```
  public List<Message> messages;
```

Whatever I name that variable, is the same name all of the child elements get.  I am sure this has been answered elsewhere, but I cannot find anything that will take care of my issue.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you post your `Message` class?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found the easy way to do this without adding more dependencies.  You just use the annotations:

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Messages")
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Message")
```

This question is what pointed me in the right direction.
[Jackson XML globally set element name for container types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904250/jackson-xml-globally-set-element-name-for-container-types).
You can also read about this annotation on the github page [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml)

Comment: congrats on finding a more elegant solution.

Comment: God bless you and you soul

Answer (score 6):

Try JAXB Annotations like this:

```
 @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Messages")
  // XmlElement sets the name of the entities
  @XmlElement(name = "Message")
  public List<Message> messages;
```

See http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations for using JAXB annotations with Jackson.

There's a good JAXB tutorial here:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html

and here:

https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/index.html

Comment: @jhamm If you haven't done so, you'll also need to add the jackson-xc jar as a dependency.  You'll also need to tell the ObjectMapper to use JAXB annotations.   See section "Registering JAXB annotation introspector" in http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations

Answer (score 5):

This works perfectly fine for List of Strings.

## XML

```
<Messages>
     <Message>msg1</Message>
     <Message>msg2</Message>
     <Message>msg3</Message>
</Messages>
```

## Jackson Code

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Messages")
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Message")
public List<String> messages;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also try using:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Messages")
class Messages{
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Message")
    List<String> message = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
       this.message.add(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As another option you can do it without annotations by changing the XML. You would change the XML to,

```
<messages>
  <Message>
    <value>"foo"</value>
  </Message>
  <Message>
    <value>"bar"</value>
  </Message>
</messages>
```

and change the Java to

```
class Foobar {
  List<Message> messages;
}
class Message {
  String value;
}
```

Then Messages would contain two objects of the Message class, one where the value member equals "foo" and the other where the value member equals "bar".